# Opening Port in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, debugging, docker, port

I'm attempting to run a node.js application in debug mode in one Docker container, and attach a debugger from another container onto the application running in the first container.

As such, I'm trying to open up port 5858 to the outside world. However, when I `--link` another container to the first container (with alias `firstContainer`), and run `nmap -p 5858 firstContainer`, I find that port 5858 is closed. The first container has told me that the node.js application is listening on port 5858, I've exposed the port in the Dockerfile, and I've also bound the ports to the corresponding port on my machine (although, I'm not certain that's necessary). When I run `nmap` on port 8080, all is successful.

How can I open up port 5858 on a Docker container such that I can attach a debugger to this port?

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openshift/base-centos7

# This image provides a Node.JS environment you can use to run your Node.JS
# applications.

MAINTAINER SoftwareCollections.org <sclorg@redhat.com>

EXPOSE 8080 5858

ENV NODEJS_VERSION 0.10

LABEL io.k8s.description="Platform for building and running Node.js 0.10 applications" \
      io.k8s.display-name="Node.js 0.10" \
      io.openshift.expose-services="8080:http" \
      io.openshift.tags="builder,nodejs,nodejs010"

RUN yum install -y \
    https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/v8314/epel-7-x86_64/download/rhscl-v8314-epel-7-x86_64.noarch.rpm \
    https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/nodejs010/epel-7-x86_64/download/rhscl-nodejs010-epel-7-x86_64.noarch.rpm && \
    yum install -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs nodejs010 && \
    yum clean all -y

# Copy the S2I scripts from the specific language image to $STI_SCRIPTS_PATH
COPY ./s2i/bin/ $STI_SCRIPTS_PATH

# Each language image can have 'contrib' a directory with extra files needed to
# run and build the applications.
COPY ./contrib/ /opt/app-root

# Drop the root user and make the content of /opt/app-root owned by user 1001
RUN chown -R 1001:0 /opt/app-root
USER 1001

# Set the default CMD to print the usage of the language image
CMD $STI_SCRIPTS_PATH/usage
```

Run with:

```
docker run -P -p 5858:5858 -p 8080:8080 --name=firstContainer nodejs-sample-app
```

Taken from/built with instructions from [here](https://github.com/openshift/sti-nodejs/tree/master/0.10).

Thanks.

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you'd just have shared your `Dockerfile` since now all we have is your description and that's like navigating blind. Since you give us little to go on, try: you seem to use bridge mode; do `docker run -P …` (note the uppercase) and then see with `docker ps` on which host port your container port `5858` has been mapped. We take it from there …

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas My apologies, I'll update the description.

Answer (score 3):

`-P` automagically maps any exposed ports within a container to a random port on host machine, while `-p` allows explicit mapping of ports.  Using the `--link` flag allows two docker containers to communicate with each other, but does nothing to expose the ports to the outside world (outside the docker private network).

Comment: If I run the command `docker run -it --name sandbox -h sandbox --link firstContainer:firstContainer linuxconfig/sandbox /bin/bash
`, and run said `nmap -p 5858 firstContainer` command, I find that the port is still closed. Might this have something to do with a firewall?

Comment: I don't think you should link a container to itself, but also in order for the `-P` flag to work, ports must be exposed within the container via `EXPOSE PORT` command in the Dockerfile.  Firewall should not affect what docker lists via `docker ps`.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not linking the container to itself, I'm linking a second container that just runs the shell. I'm exposing the ports in the Dockerfile that I've listed. Not certain why the `5858` port is closed.

Comment: run `docker ps -a` and see if any stopped containers are taking up that port.

Comment: Ports column is empty.

Comment: You are running: `docker run -P --name=firstContainer nodejs-sample-app` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94460/discussion-between-carter-and-citronen).